# Why won't python allow me to delete files?

Tags: python, file-io

I've created a python script that gets a list of files from a text file and deletes them if they're empty.  It correctly detects empty files but it doesn't want to delete them.  It gives me:

```
(32, 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process')
```

I've used two different tools to check whether the files are locked or not and I'm certain that they are not.  I used sysinternals process explorer and LockHunter.  Furthermore, I'm able to just manually delete the files myself.  I obviously don't want to do that for all of them as there are hundreds in various locations.

The script:

```
import os.path
import sys

def DeleteFilesFromListIfBlank(PathToListOfFiles):
    ListOfFiles = open(PathToListOfFiles)
    FilesToCheck = [];
    for line in ListOfFiles.readlines():
        if(len(line) > 1):
            line = line.rstrip();
            FilesToCheck.append(line)
    print "Found %s files to check.  Starting check." % len(FilesToCheck)

    FilesToRemove = [];
    for line in FilesToCheck:        
        #print "Opening %s" % line
        try:
            ActiveFile = open(line);
            Length = len(ActiveFile.read())
            if(Length < 691 and ActiveFile.read() == ""):
                print "Deleting %s" % line
                os.unlink(line);
            else:
                print "Keeping %s" % line
        except IOError,message:
            print "Could not open file: $s" % message
        except Exception as inst:
            print inst.args

DeleteFilesFromListIfBlank("C:\\ListOfResx.txt")
```

I've tried using both os.unlink and os.remove.  I'm running Python 2.6 on Vista64

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to call `.close()` on the file object before you try and delete it.

Edit: And really you shouldn't be opening the file at all. `os.stat()` will tell you the size of a file (and 9 other values) without ever opening the file.

This (I think) does the same thing but is a little cleaner (IMHO):

```
import os

_MAX_SIZE = 691

def delete_if_blank(listFile):
    # Make a list of files to check.
    with open(listFile) as listFile:
        filesToCheck = filter(None, (line.rstrip() for line in listFile.readlines()))

    # listFile is automatically closed now because we're out of the 'with' statement.

    print "Found %u files to check. Starting check." % len(filesToCheck)

    # Remove each file.
    for filename in filesToCheck:
        if os.stat(filename).st_size < _MAX_SIZE:
            print "Deleting %s" % filename
            os.remove(filename)
        else:
            print "Keeping %s" % filename
```

Answer (score 9):

Try ActiveFile.close() before doing the unlink.

Also, reading the whole file isn't necessary, you can use os.path.getsize(filename) == 0.

Answer (score 6):

It's **you** that has the file open - you need to close it before trying to delete it:

```
ActiveFile = open(line);
Length = len(ActiveFile.read())
ActiveFile.close()   # Insert this line!
```

or just get the filesize without opening the file:

```
Length = os.path.getsize(line)
```

Answer (score 4):

Are you opening each file and then trying to delete it?  If so, try closing it first.

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to close the filehandle `ActiveFile` before you try to delete it.